# React Native - Adding items to FlatList using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to implement a simple ToDo list exercise app with Redux.

I have a `TextInput`, a `Button` and a `FlatList`, the items are stored as an array in the `store` and handled by a `reducer`.
When the button is pressed an item with the text from the input should be 
added to the list.

Currently when I press the button nothing happens, the list does not seem to render and new elements are not added.
I suspect something could be wrong in the onPress handling but I'm not sure, I could have made mistakes elsewhere, I'm pretty new to React Native

Any help for figuring this out is welcome.

This is my code so far (without the imports):

action

```
export const addItem = item =>({type: ADD_ITEM, payload: item});
```

reducer

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
};

const itemReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_ITEM:
            return { ...state, items: [...state.items, action.payload] };
        default: 
            return state;
    }

};

export default itemReducer;
```

store

```
const store = createStore(itemReducer);

export default store;
```

input form

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addItem: item => dispatch(addItem(item))
    };
};

class ItemInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { itemText: 'Add an item' };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        //event.preventDefault();
        const { itemText } = this.state;
        this.props.addItem( { itemText } );
        this.setState({ itemText: "" });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                    onChangeText={(itemText) => this.setState({itemText})}
                    value={this.state.itemText}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={this.handleSubmit}
                    title="Submit"
                    color="#841584"
                />
        </View>
        );
    }
}

export default ItemInput = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemInput);
```

list

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { items: state.items };
  };

class ItemList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        };

        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
        this.keyExtractor = this.keyExtractor.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5', paddingTop:20}}>
            <FlatList
                ref='listRef'
                data={this.props.items}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

    renderItem({item, index}) {
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemList);
```

todo list component

```
class ToDoList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ItemInput/>
                <List/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

App (root)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ToDoList/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The part inside your `handleSubmit` here `this.props.addItem( { itemText } );` is creating an object like this: `{itemText: 'Some input text'}`. But `renderItem` method is trying to use `item.title` instead of `itemText`. Can you fix that and report if it does any better?

Comment: https://github.com/anil-sidhu/Redux-with-react-native-tutorial

this is the example with simple code made by me. if facing issue let me know

Comment: You might have to use component will recieve props to re render your screen. Or you could make your ItemList extend pure component instead which handles this for you. Also verify if you are getting your data on the right format in mapstatetoprops because your keys might have been mixed up.

Comment: @naffiq Thanks to your suggestion I found the issue, it was with the elements mapping. :)